# How can I use available CPU from other computers in my network

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I am running many multi-threading python programs and my CPU is almost always on 100%.

I'm not expert in this area but is it possible to use CPU from others employees that are in my network because the only issue on my PC is that I need more cores to process data faster the RAM is ok from 16GB 10 GB is used.

We are using Windows 7,8.1 and 10.

Comment: It depends what the work is that you are running. You could run the same application on multiple machines with TCP sockets so each process can talk to each other, but I too am not an expert, so I wouldn't be able to go into detail about this :P

Comment: try https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing . you should be able to find a solution there. However Clustering is a very dificult topic. Keep that in mind

Comment: yeah I can run apps from multiple machines but then I have to check out now an then does the app still works. With my way I have one app running from my machine and using shared CPU resources. It is easier to track apps and I can scale how much I need resources. P.S. @T.G I will check the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As out of the box -solution, no.

What you are describing is a grid. Grid computing does exist, but it is not something that is delivered alongside Python or any programming language.

You would need a server, where worker clients connect and request for more work when they are idle, and deliver results. You could use an existing framework (Boinc for example) or build your own client and server, but this would not be a simple task to make it work right.

For example, your server needs to handle a situation where it hands a task to a worker, but the worker does not seem to be sending back any results. At which stage you would declare the worker dead and resubmit the task to another worker?  If the first worker was just slow, you would have two results delivered for the same task. What to do then, especially if the results differ?

This would also require co-operation from administrators of that network segment. They would need to maintain the array of workers and install your code alongside any other software they manage in the computers. You would also need to convince your information security people that your ability to run arbitrary code in every computer in the network does not compromise security. You could mitigate this by containerisation, but this adds another layer of complexity.

Then there is the question of performance. Grid computing has a tail effect. A grid starts processing tasks quickly, but when you approach the end of your run, the last tasks take a long time to complete. This is because of unresponsive and very slow workers doing the last tasks. At some point you would need to declare that you do not want to wait any longer, and actually start processing the last tasks locally to mitigate this. Again, not very complicated but building the logic to do so adds to your program.

All this requires quite a lot of work and maintenance, and programming resources from you to make your program and its tasks suitable for grid (tasks need to be embarrassingly parallel).

If this is something you do 24/7 and you want to use computing resources standing idle overnight, it might be useful. If this is not a constantly running thing, it might be cheaper to just buy CPU power from a cloud and run parts of your tasks there. Sure, there is a cost attached, but you will easily spend that money to coffee and biscuits for meetings with your infosec people. Adding work from you and administrators on top of that, there might not be a business case to do this.

Having said that, there are a couple of grid computing projects for Python if you decide to follow this route. The wiki page mentioned in comments lists a couple of them that are still active. You might get some help from there in task and job management.